Attention, FFN Add&Norm Order

The actual structure Add to X Attention, then FFN.
I my structure on the right image, only the tiny $ \delta e$ generated by the FFN is added to X.
Therefor there is no Attention noise after each layer of Encoder/Decoder block.

I think the right hand side shows the case where the input is directly connected to the output through a residual connection. On the left hand side this is not the case because the attention activation is added prior to the next residual step

This sounds like a similar question asked recently in this site and see my answer there. Basically one potential drawback of your proposed approach could be that the model might not fully leverage the interactions captured by the multi-head attention (MHA) block since the adjustments from the FFN are applied directly to the original input $\mathbf{x}$ with the potential loss of information from the reduced interaction between the MHA and FFN outputs, rather than to a consistent sequential residual tandem of the MHA and FFN outputs of the transformer.

and why the sequential approche is better than the one shown in this post ?
